# Getting top url from inside iFrame

Tags: php

I am hosting a quiz on my website from an iFrame. I want the quiz share to share the url of the site hosting the iFrame and not the IFrame url.

I have tried:

```
 echo $_SERVER['URI'];  and $_POST['URI']
```

Which return nothing. I also want to include paramaters. Here is the url: http://quizzerland.com/?q=f

Answer (score 1):

From the server perspective the `iFrame` is a stand-alone website and is requested separately by the browser.

If you control the code on the hosting / parent website, you can make the parent website pass its URL to the iFrame with Javascript.

Just add something like this at the bottom:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.parent_window_url = window.location.toString(); /* or window.location.host */
</script>
```

Then in the quiz's page (the iframe) javascript code you have access to the variable `parent_window_url` which contains the parent's URL. You can POST it via AJAX to the server or include it in URLs you want to generate dynamically.